# how can i change a specific bar color in chart.js color chartjs

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

i want to change the color of the chosen bar in bar chart I found this code but When i run the code this error shown **myChart.getElementsAtEvent is not a function
at HTMLCanvasElement.ChangeColor**

here is my code

html:

````
    ```
               <div class="chartBox">
                  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                  <input type="color" id ="colorPicker" hidden/>                      
                </div>
    ```
````

Javascript code:

````
```

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

        <script type="">
            var color = '#456212';
            var lastIndex = null;
            var canvas = document.getElementById("myChart");

          document.getElementById("my-select").addEventListener("change", changeChart);
          document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", filterChart);




          var label = <%- JSON.stringify(x)%>
          var data = [<%= y %>]
          const originalLabels = label;
          const originalData = data ;


          var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
          var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: originalLabels,
              datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: originalData,
                backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
              }]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }
            }
          });
canvas.addEventListener("click", ChangeColor, false);

     colorPicker = document.getElementById('colorPicker');

     colorPicker.addEventListener("change", getColor, false);


    function getColor(e){

       //
        console.log(this.lastIndex)
        myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[lastIndex] =  e.target.value;
        console.log(e.target.value);
        myChart.update();

    }


 function ChangeColor(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var activePoints = myChart.getElementsAtEvent(e);
        lastIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
        this.color = myChart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[lastIndex];
        console.log('Before', this.color);
        var colorPicker = document.getElementById('colorPicker').click();
        //console.log('After',this.color);
    }

</script>

       
```
````

how can i change a specific bar color

i want the user click on the bar then chose the color or the opposite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared a sample. Clicking on the bar element, the color picker is visible and when you choose the color, the chart will be updated with new color.

I think it's better to use `onClick` option provided by CHART.JS instead of add event listener to the canvas because CHART.JS option is providing the elements affected by the click event.

To simplify the sample, be aware that the backgroundColor must be set as an array with the original colors for each bar (but you can add additional logic to manage it).

```js
let selected = undefined;
const chartData = {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [{
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor:  ['cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan'],
    data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40],
  }]
};
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    onClick(evt, elements, chart) {
      if (elements.length) {
        selected = elements;
        const colorPicker = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
        colorPicker.click();
      }
    }
  }
});
document.getElementById("colorPicker").addEventListener("change", setColor);
function setColor() {
  if (selected && selected.length) {
    const colorPicker = document.getElementById("colorPicker");
    for (const el of selected) {
      const {datasetIndex, index} = el;
      const dataset = myChart.data.datasets[datasetIndex];
      dataset.backgroundColor.splice(index, 1, colorPicker.value);
    }
    myChart.update();
  }
}
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <input id="colorPicker" type="color" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: good to hear that! Maybe you could set it the correct answer, helpful for all other users. Thank you

Comment: I accepted the answer I don't know if this is what you mean